# Why ServicePointManager isn't recommended for new developments

Tags: c#, .net, httpclient, servicepointmanager

I'm trying to intercept the validation of the returned server certificates in a .net framework application.
I came with two solutions:

1. Use `HttpClientHandler.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (httpRequestMessage, cert, cetChain, policyErrors) =>{ my implementation}`
2. Use `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (httpRequestMessage, cert, cetChain, policyErrors) =>{ my implementation}`

Is there advantage for the use of one on another?

From the [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager?view=netframework-4.7.2) it says

> We don't recommend that you use the ServicePointManager class for new
> development. Instead, use the System.Net.Http.HttpClient class.

Is there any reason for that , other than ServicePointManager not being used in .net Core?

Comment: Using `ServicePointManager` will set it for everything which is really bad. Much safer to constrain it to just the calls that it is needed for.

Comment: Why are you using `ServerCertificateValidationCallback` instead of eg trusting the server's certificate on your machine?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos for example if I don't want the request to fail if revocation failed on RevocationStatusUnknown

Comment: Why would that happen if the certificate is trusted? The whole point of using HTTPS and certificates is to ensure you're talking to the real server instead of a fake. Not encryption. If you disable verification you essentially disable HTTPS. Besides, you *do* care about revocation, a lot. When certificates get stolen you *do* want to know whether they were revoked or not

Comment: _"Why XYZ isn't recommended for new developments"_ - Most often, it is simply because there are successors to XYZ and the legacy stuff is planned to get abandoned, phased out or _at least_ not supported. They may or may not come with old bugs and issues that will be dealt with that way.

Comment: @Fildor I must say I'm not convinced there was ever a time that `ServerCertificateValidationCallback` *should* have been used, outside of debugging. So not just new code, even old code.

Comment: @Charlieface I guess so, yes. I was talking a little more generally.

Answer (score 0):

`ServicePointManager` seems to have a few methods marked as obsolete: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager?view=net-6.0#:~:text=this%20ServicePointManager%20object.-,Methods,-Equals(Object)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager?view=net-6.0#:%7E:text=this%20ServicePointManager%20object.-,Methods,-Equals(Object))

Looks like new classed with updated methods now exist. `ServicePointManager` is probably being kept around largely for compatibility with old versions.